# OTP fill in appium selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, one-time-password, totp

[Shreenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqdo8.png)
I have fixed OTP for app login ( ex:123456 )

I added appium detail here and I tried send_keys to fill that OTP but not working for me

Appium says  ( Using XPath locators is not recommended and can lead to fragile tests. Ask your development team to provide unique accessibility locators instead!  )

Is there any other way to fill this OTP page ?

Please anyone give me idea to fill that OTP

Sendkeys are not working to fill this OTP and unable to write xpath also please anyone help me to fill ( 123456 ) this oTP to that boxes.

Comment: that's just a notice/warning.  Include the exception you receive when trying to send the keys along with the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Element you are referring here and trying to interact (use `sendkey`) won't work because it is the `Textview` (as I see in the shared screenshot). You should find `EditText` element, that is designed for input.

The message from Appium about `xpath` usage is recommendation, and in the current case I don't believe that it has any relation with the problem described.